# Quick question on inner products and linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, inner-products

Quick question:
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space and $T$,$U$ linear operators. 
If  $\left<Ta,b\right> = \left<Ua,b\right>  \;\forall a,b \in V$  then $T = U$?

I am not sure if this reasoning is correct:
If that statement is true for all $a,b \in V$ then in particular for $b = 0$ we have:
$$\left<(T-U)a,0\right> = 0 \quad\forall a \in V \Rightarrow (T-U)a = 0 \; \forall a \in V$$
and then $U = T$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $\langle (T - U) a, 0 \rangle = 0$ holds for any $T$ and $U$ whatsoever since we always have $\langle x, 0 \rangle = 0$.  So, you cannot conclude anything from this.

To get a correct proof, you would need to apply the hypothesis with $b := (T - U) a$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, the original statement is true? if $\left<Ta,b\right> = \left<Ua,b\right>  \;\forall a,b \in V$ then $U = T$ ?

Comment: @user8989 Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly true that

$\langle Ta, b \rangle = \langle Ua, b \rangle \Longrightarrow \langle (T - U)a, b \rangle = 0 \tag 1$

for all $a, b \in V$, so the line of reasoning is correct up to this point.
It is, however, false that

$\langle (T - U)a, 0 \rangle \Longrightarrow (T - U)a = 0; \tag 2$

if fact,

$\langle (T - U)a, 0 \rangle = 0, \tag 3$

*always*, no matter what $(T - U)a$ might be.  This follows from the standard linearity properties of and inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$; that is,

$\langle x, y + z \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle + \langle x, z \rangle; \tag 4$

whence

$\langle x, 0 \rangle = \langle x, 0 + 0 \rangle  = \langle x, 0 \rangle +  \langle x, 0 \rangle \Longrightarrow \langle x, 0 \rangle = 0. \tag 5$

Since

$\langle (T - U)a, b \rangle = 0 \tag 6$

holds for all $a, b \in V$ by hypothesis, we are free to set

$b = (T - U)a \tag 7$

in (6) and then we obtain

$\Vert (T - U)a \Vert^2 = \langle (T - U)a, (T - U)a \rangle = 0, \tag 8$

from which we conclude

$(T - U)a = 0 \tag 8$

for all $a \in V$;  Thus

$Ta = Ua. \tag 9$

In arguing (6)-(9) I have used the proposition that

$\langle x, x \rangle  = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x = 0, \tag{10}$

which is generally taken as axiomatic for inner products $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed answer!

Comment: You are most welcome!